# How can I retrieve all property values from a list of common objects?

Tags: c#, linq, collections, extension-methods

I want to retrieve all single properties from a collection as an array:

```
class Foo{
   public string Bar { get; set; }
   public string Baz { get; set;}
}
```

I want to get i.e. all Bar properties from the collection

```
var list = new List<Foo>();

string[] allBars = list. ....
```

and how does it go on???

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use:

```
string[] allBars = list.Select(foo => foo.Bar).ToArray();
```

I would only convert this to an array if you specifically need it to be in an array.  If your goal is just to output the "Bar" list, you could just do:

```
var allBars = list.Select(foo => foo.Bar); // Will produce IEnumerable<string>
foreach(var bar in allBars)
{
    // Do something with bar
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it. Linq was specifically designed to make these kinds of list transformations simple and painless.

Comment: Thanks for this hint. Nice and simple. I will use it for Binding to an Array in OracleCommand (ODP.NET)

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = from foo element in foo_bar_list
                        where foo.Bar == ""
                        select new
                        {
                            class1.Baz
                        };
```